# DateRangePicker is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am trying to use this lib: https://github.com/themesberg/tailwind-datepicker

***webpack.mix.js*** file:

```
mix.setPublicPath('htdocs');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'htdocs/js').
    js('resources/js/dateRangePicker.js', 'htdocs/js');
```

***resources/js/dateRangePicker.js*** file:

```
import DateRangePicker from '@themesberg/tailwind-datepicker/DateRangePicker';
```

***app.blade file***

...

```
<script type="module" src="{{mix('js/dateRangePicker.js')}}"></script>
<script>
   const dateRangePickerEl = document.getElementById('datepickstart');
   new DateRangePicker(dateRangePickerEl, {
     // options
   }
</script>
```

...

But i am getting error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DateRangePicker is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to import and work with js modules?